# Google Script Trigger Collapse Group Problem

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a problem with time triggers.
I want groups in the sheets to collapse every 30 minutes. I record the macro and set the trigger in script editor.

This is my code:

```
function zwin() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:H').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getColumnGroup(9, 1).collapse();
};
```

I set the time trigger (every 1 minute to check if it works), and keep getting this problem:

> Exception: A column group does not exist with index 9 and group depth 1

As you can see, the group index is correct: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS9kG.png

But when I try to run the script manually, It works perfectly. It collapses the group I created.
I keep getting this problem in every sheet with groups I create, the only difference is the group index (which I change in the code addording to its position).

I tried to delete the group and create it again, change the range in the code - nothing works.

What am I doing wrong and how to make it work?

[EDIT]
All I had to do is to manually define the spreadsheet where I want to trigger the script. Added code:

```
 function zwin() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("myspreadsheetid");
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName("thesheetname").getColumnGroup(9, 1).collapse();
};
```

but I got this message because I just simply misspelled the id:

> Unexpected error while getting the method or property openById on object SpreadsheetApp

Make sure you don't misspell the id which you can find here:

> The id is the xxx part in https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXX/edit#gid=0

openByUrl works as well:

```
function zwin() {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("myspreadsheeturl");
      spreadsheet.getSheetByName("thesheetname").getColumnGroup(9, 1).collapse();
    };
```

And it works!

Comment: One problem could be that ranges like 'A:H' tend to create nulls in google apps scripts between last row and max rows.  Also it could be that running it from a trigger causes it to open the spreadsheet only on the server where there is no user interface.  Why do you want to run it on a trigger when you not even looking at it.  Perhaps it would make more sense to run it from an onOpen().

Comment: Acheived the result I wanted by manually defining the spreadsheet where I want to trigger the sript :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### When you run your function on time-based trigger, there is no active spreadsheet

- A time-based trigger runs independtly of the spreadsheet
- It also runs when the spreadsheet is closed (and thus there is no active spreadsheet)
- Thus, you need to manually define on which spreadsheet and sheet you want to run the trigger
- You can do it by e.g. [calling the spreadsheet by its id](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) and the sheet [by its name](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)

Sample:

```js
function zwin() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("YOUR-SHEET-ID");
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName("NAME_OF_THE_SHEET").getColumnGroup(9, 1).collapse();
};
```

Comment: I used your code, entered the name of sreadsheet but got this message instead: Unexpected error while getting the method or property openById on object SpreadsheetApp. So I instead of openById, I put: OpenByUrl and it works! Thanks so much!

Comment: `openByUrl` is also possible. If you have a problem with `openById`, maybe you misspelled the `id`? The `id` is the `xxx` part in `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXX/edit#gid=0`.

Comment: Oooh, right. Yes, you're right, I indeed misspelled the id :)